# Django Login suddenly stopped working - timing out

Tags: django, gunicorn

My Django project used to work perfectly fine for the last 90 days.
There has been no new code deployment during this time.

Running supervisor -> gunicorn to serve the application and to the front nginx.

Unfortunately it just stopped serving the login page (standard framework login).

I wrote a small view that checks if the DB connection is working and it comes up within seconds.

```
def updown(request):
    from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse
    from django.db import connections
    from django.db.utils import OperationalError


    status = True

    # Check database connection
    if status is True:
        db_conn = connections['default']
        try:
            c = db_conn.cursor()
        except OperationalError:
            status = False
            error = 'No connection to database'
    else:
        status = True

    if status is True:
        message = 'OK'
    elif status is False:
        message = 'NOK' + ' \n' + error

    return HttpResponse(message)
```

This delivers back an OK.

But the second I am trying to reach /admin or anything else requiring the login, it times out.

```
wget http://127.0.0.1:8000
--2022-07-20 22:54:58--  http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /business/dashboard/ [following]
--2022-07-20 22:54:58--  http://127.0.0.1:8000/business/dashboard/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /account/login/?next=/business/dashboard/ [following]
--2022-07-20 22:54:58--  http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/?    next=/business/dashboard/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.

--2022-07-20 22:55:30--  (try: 2)  http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/login/?next=/business/dashboard/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

Supervisor / Gunicorn Log is not helpful at all:

```
[2022-07-20 23:06:34 +0200] [980] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-07-20 23:06:34 +0200] [980] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (980)
[2022-07-20 23:06:34 +0200] [980] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-07-20 23:06:34 +0200] [986] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 986
[2022-07-20 23:08:01 +0200] [980] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:986)
[2022-07-20 23:08:02 +0200] [980] [WARNING] Worker with pid 986 was terminated due to signal 9
[2022-07-20 23:08:02 +0200] [1249] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1249
[2022-07-20 23:12:26 +0200] [980] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:1249)
[2022-07-20 23:12:27 +0200] [980] [WARNING] Worker with pid 1249 was terminated due to signal 9
[2022-07-20 23:12:27 +0200] [1515] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 1515
```

Nginx is just giving:

```
 502 Bad Gateway
```

I don't see anything in the logs, I don't see any error when running the dev server from Django, also Sentry is not showing anything. Totally lost.

I am running Django 4.0.x and all libraries are updated.

Answer (score 0):

The check up script for the database is only checking the connection. Due to misconfiguration of the database replication, the db was connecting and also reading, but when writing it hang.

The login page tries to write a session to the tables, which failed in this case.